# Chomedriver selenium doesn't work under vpn

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, vpn

I encountered an issue rather strange. When I run python scripts with selenium under fortinet vpn they get stuck. It never gets past "data:," at the address bar. How fortinet detects chromedriver?

**Example code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
browser.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

**No VPN:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFBF1.png

**with VPN:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcE0W.png

**update 1**

Tried modifying _cdc as suggested in this question but had no progress:
[Can a website detect when you are using selenium with chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver)

**update 2**

Just tried using Firefox and Safari. Both work fine under the VPN. It definitely blocks chromedriver on some way.

Comment: Please share code examples, logs, or outputs.

Comment: We're having the same issue - have you made any progress troubleshooting this? I'm going to reach out to fortinet support to see if they have any ideas or suggestions.

We tried downgrading chrome and chromedriver to version 84, and also upgrading the forticlient.

We're also having this issue on MacOS 10.15.6. I'm not sure if you're using a Mac or Windows?

Comment: Not really. Mac too. I just started using Remote Desktop. Not that practical but it was useful as a workaround. Could you give a shoutout if you get any updates? I am curious. Hope you get a solution!

Comment: I opened a ticket with fortinet support with step by step instructions. Will let you know what I find out. I also opened a chromedriver bug - although I don't know how well the chromedriver folks will be able to troubleshoot without a fortinet SSL vpn client. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=3601

Comment: We're having the same issue in MAC, does anyone found a solution for this